# php SELECT (count) in mysql/pdo WHERE formatted date

Tags: php, mysql, date, select, count

I need to select (count) rows with a specific date formatted by YEAR-MONTH-DAY.

i try

```
 $date = $_GET['date'];

 // requete qui recupere les evenements
$result = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM evenement WHERE STR_TO_DATE(start, '%Y-%m-%d') = $date";

 // connexion a la base de donnees
 try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=', '', '');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
 exit('Impossible de se connecter a la base de donnees.');
 }
 $sth = $bdd->query($result);
 echo json_encode($sth->fetchColumn());
```

where date variable is a date with that format. i want to count rows and return the number of rows with that date.

i also try

```
$result = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM evenement WHERE DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%d') = $date";
```

and

```
$result = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM evenement WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE(start), '%Y-%m-%d') = $date";
```

but nothing works

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is open to SQL_Injection... Please use prepared statements!

Comment: the value of `$date` is?

Comment: oh thanks for advice @Naruto

Comment: @Fred-ii- $date get value from an array with dates. wich have that format.

Comment: 20150907? you didn't specify that. I need specifics.

Comment: `var_dump($date);` that's what I need to see and what the "value" of the GET array is, before I can submit my answer.

Comment: You should use prepared statements. Inserting user data direct to your query opens you to SQL injections. The `$date` in `= $date`  should be surrounded by `'`s, because it is a string.

Comment: you have another answer, I'm out of this loop.

Comment: @NinjTsax instead of an edit to show what your final query was that led to your solution, you should be posting your own answer instead. Stack does let you do that you know ;-) and I for one, think it would be best if you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The responses and comments all led to this answer

```
$result = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM evenement WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE(start), '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE('".$date."')"
```

the problem was that the $date variable need DATE($date) and in SELECT need quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your constant to a date, not the column.  So, my first attempt would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM evenement
WHERE start = DATE('$date');
```

However, that might not work.  You might need to use `str_to_date()` with the appropriate format.

The reason this method is better is because the optimizer can take advantage of an index on `evenement(start)`.

Comment: Doesn't `$date` not need be quoted?

Comment: @Fred-ii- you are right need quoted. so both answers make my code work.
My $date variable need DATE($date). so you suggestion make me think about it and Gordon Linoff 's answer confirmed that.

Comment: @NinjTsax Funny you should say that. I had that very same thought earlier: *"both answers given will give the OP their solution"* - Now, how bizarre is that? ;-)

Comment: ...and this answer should reflect it before accepting it @NinjTsax I think Gordon should have known this. His experience far exceeds mine ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- haha confoundedly strange.. Thank you all ! :D

Comment: @Fred-ii- . . . Actually, I was thinking it should be a parameter and not built-into the string.  My real point was to do the conversion on the parameter and not on the column.

Answer (score 0):

Change like this

```
$result = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM evenement WHERE DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%d') = '".$date."'";
```

You need to enclose $date in '' quotes, else it will perform subtraction like(2014-10-01 = 2003)

Comment: and "why" should they "change like this"?

Comment: @Fred-ii- in the table im searching for that date. Dates have different format